# Why can't Django model object be added to a list?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to add an instance of a model in Django to a list and get these results (from Shell):

1. Import the model and instantiate an object

```
>>> from base.models import Service
>>> s = Service.objects.first()
```

2. Check the type of the object

```
>>> type(s) 
<class 'base.models.Service'>
```

3. Instantiate the list

```
>>> mylist = []
```

4. Try to add the model object to the list

```
>>> mylist += s
```

5. Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Service' object is not iterable
```

Why exactly can I not add a model instance to the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *three* options:

```
mylist += [s]
```

or:

```
mylist.append(s)
```

or:

```
mylist.extend([s])
```

---

**Why do you get your error?**

`mylist += s` is same as `mylist.extend(s)` which fails if the one adding is non-iterable. Whereas wrapping `s` in squares brackets makes it a `<class 'list'>` which is now iterable. Thus, `mylist += [s]` works in the same way `mylist.extend([s])` also works.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```py
mylist.append(s)
```

instead. Remember that you're basically doing

```py
mylist = mylist + s
```

and, by definition of the `+` operator on lists, the `s` must be an iterable object as well.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend?rq=1) for a better explanation of the `+` operator (or `.extend()`) vs append.